# Handler response in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am new in NodeJS, and I am working an an example:

```
function test(req,res){
    var path = urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length)];
    console.log("try to redirect to:"+path);
    http.get(path,function(res_server){
        //how to send the data from res_server to res
    });
}
```

And the `urls` is an array of url.

I wonder how can I send the data from the `res_server` to the original client `response`?

BTW, the url maybe `http` or `https`.

---

update

```
var urls=["url1","url2","url3"];
var path = urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length)]; // find an random item from the array
```

---

update:2

Fine, this is the complete simple test script:

```
var http=require("http");
http.createServer(function(req, res1) {
  var url = 'http://www.google.com.hk/images/srpr/logo11w.png';

  var hp=require("http");
  hp.get(url, function(res2) {
    res2.pipe(res1);
  });
}).listen(3000);
```

It works, but if you change `http://www.google.com.hk/...logo..png` to `https:/www.google.....png`

It will throw error:

```
http.js:1840
    throw new Error('Protocol:' + options.protocol + ' not supported.');
          ^
Error: Protocol:https: not supported.
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:1840:11)
    at Object.exports.get (http.js:1847:21)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\maven\Desktop\t.js:6:6)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2108:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1966:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:525:27)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not fully understand your example. Looks strange to me. However best would be to pipe the request response into the server response:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res1) {
  var path = url.format({
    protocol: 'http:',
    host: 'www.google.com'
  });

  http.get(path, function(res2) {
    res2.pipe(res1);
  });
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: I update my post. And btw, my application run on the `http` mode, so if the `path` is something like 'https:/xxx', I will get error:`Error: Protocol:https: not supported.`

Comment: Ah okay makes sense now. About the protocol error I assume your url is somehow wrong (missing double slash "https://blabla.com"?) as there is no reason why a http server should not be able to do https requests.

Comment: @hguser seems to me we found the issue. If you use url.format to generate an url note that the protocol property has no slashes (e.g. "{ protocol: 'https:' }")

Answer (score 5):

Change `var http = require('http');` to `var http = require('https');`

Comment: Exactly what the problem was for me!